# Minimum placement of circles in polygon

Tags: circles, area, polygons

I have a variably sized 4 sided polygon in 2D space.

I can draw circles inside this polygon which have a fixed radius (500 meters).

I need to cover all the surface area of this polygon, using these fixed sized circles, however I want to draw the least amount of circles possible (require total surface area coverage with minimal number of total circles).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGNxB.png) is a simple diagram for a square shape (this is made by hand, all circles should be the same size, I also do not think this is an optimal example, but unsure).

Can somebody help with an algorithm which would solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Packing and covering problems are hard (as in *"NP-hard"*, though I'm not exactly sure of that) and riddled with [counter-intuitive results](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html). There are algorithms (see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705922/finding-a-cover-of-a-set-of-points-with-circles/4720416#4720416), for instance) which are known to produce *"not very bad"* (but not necessarily optimal) solutions; if that suits you, go for it.

And if you have to do this just once, do it by hand.

[image]